# Why is my confirm password field not firing validation at all (react-hook-form)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, input, react-hook-form

Here is a codesandbox to see my problem replicated: https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-haslett-1c8sw?file=/pages/index.js

I want to ensure the confirmPassword field matches the password field, however it will always say "Passwords match", it never changes.

I have followed the docs however I cannot seem to get the functionality im after. I have set the mode to `onChange`

Here is my form:

```
import { SubmitHandler, useForm, useFormState } from "react-hook-form";

function IndexPage() {
  //Hook form
  const {
    register,
    watch,
    formState: { errors, isValid, dirtyFields }
  } = useForm({
    mode: "onChange",
    defaultValues: {
      email: "",
      password: "",
      confirmPassword: "",
      username: "",
      firstName: "",
      surname: "",
      isShop: false
    }
  });
  const { password } = watch();

  const [passwordFocused, setPasswordFocused] = useState(false);

  const onSubmit = async (data) => {
    //submit here
  };

  return (
    <>
      {/* NEW SIGNUP FORM */}
      <main className="min-h-screen flex">
        <div className="w-full flex flex-col py-12 md:w-1/2 flex-grow min-h-full">
          <div className="mt-6 h-full w-full flex flex-col md:w-96 mx-auto">
            <form
              onSubmit={onSubmit}
              autoComplete="off"
              className="space-y-6 relative flex flex-col w-full flex-1"
            >
              <span className="flex-1"></span>
              {/* STEP 1*/}
              <div>
                <div className="space-y-1">
                  <label
                    htmlFor="password"
                    className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700"
                  >
                    Password
                  </label>
                  <div className="mt-1">
                    <input
                      {...register("password", {
                        required: true,
                        minLength: 8,
                        maxLength: 50,
                        pattern: /^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d@$!%*#?&^_-]{8,}$/
                      })}
                      id="password"
                      name="password"
                      type="password"
                      autoComplete="current-password"
                      required
                      className="input w-full"
                      onFocus={() => {
                        setPasswordFocused(true);
                      }}
                      onBlur={() => {
                        setPasswordFocused(false);
                      }}
                    />
                    <span
                      className={`${
                        passwordFocused && errors.password
                          ? "max-h-46 opacity-100"
                          : "max-h-0 opacity-0"
                      } duration-500 ease-in-out transition-all flex flex-col overflow-hidden`}
                    >
                      <p className="text-gray-600 mt-2">
                        Passwords must contain:
                      </p>
                      <ul className="space-y-2">
                        <li
                          className={`mt-2 ${
                            password.length >= 8
                              ? "text-green-600"
                              : "text-gray-600"
                          }`}
                        >
                          At least 8 characters
                        </li>
                        <li
                          className={`mt-2 ${
                            /[A-Z]/.test(password)
                              ? "text-green-600"
                              : "text-gray-600"
                          }`}
                        >
                          Upper and lower case characters
                        </li>
                        <li
                          className={`mt-2 ${
                            /\d/.test(password)
                              ? "text-green-600"
                              : "text-gray-600"
                          }`}
                        >
                          At least one digit
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div
                  className={`space-y-1 ${
                    !errors.password && dirtyFields.password
                      ? "visible"
                      : "invisible"
                  } `}
                >
                  <label
                    htmlFor="password"
                    className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700"
                  >
                    Confirm password
                  </label>
                  <div className="mt-1">
                    <input
                      {...register("confirmPassword", {
                        validate: (value) =>
                          value === password || "Passwords do not match"
                      })}
                      id="confirm-password"
                      name="confirm-password"
                      type="password"
                      autoComplete="confirm-password"
                      required
                      className={`input w-full`}
                    />
                  </div>
                  {errors.confirmPassword
                    ? "Passwords do not match"
                    : "Passwords match"}
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
    </>
  );
}

export default IndexPage;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using getValues from useForm.

```
const {
    register,
    watch,
    getValues,
    formState: { errors, isValid, dirtyFields }
  } = useForm({
    mode: "onChange",
    defaultValues: {
      email: "",
      password: "",
      confirmPassword: "",
      username: "",
      firstName: "",
      surname: "",
      isShop: false
    }
  });
```

and then put that in your validation:

```
{...register("confirmPassword", {
    validate: (value) =>
           value === getValues("password")
})}
```

Display error:

```
{errors.confirmPassword && errors.confirmPassword.type === "validate" && <div>Passwords do not match</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! But sadly it has no effect :(

Comment: I added some additional code.

Comment: I have added your code to the codesandbox however it still has no effect, thanks